# how can i target span's string in click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm try to catch 'banner name' in under code.

```
<div class = 'pdf-area'>
    <ul class = 'pdf list'>
        <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:pdfDownload('/pdf_name/spec_name.pdf'); return false;"><span class="icon-left"></span> 'banner name'</a>

        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and here is my try.

```
$("div.pdf-area ul a").click(function(i) {
    var txt = $(i.target).text();
    console.log(txt);
});
```

When I run this code, I don't get the value I want.

How can I extract 'baaner name'?

(href= # -> it's not my code and don't have any autohrity that can modify this code . I only can extract value in this condition.)

Comment: I do not see any `div` with class `download-area`

Comment: sorry. modify code now.

Comment: What is the `return` there doing? Remove that, and it seems to work just fine

Comment: Instead of this: `var txt = $(i.target).text();` try this: `var txt = $(this).text().trim();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to add the click event by using the selector. Simply pass `this` as the first parameter. Then inside the function use `find()` on that object to target the `span`.

Try the following:

```js
function pdfDownload(el, link){
  var name = $(el).find('span.icon-left').text();
  console.log(name);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'pdf area'>
  <ul class = 'pdf list'>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="javascript:pdfDownload(this, '/pdf_name/spec_name.pdf'); return false;"><span class="icon-left"> 'banner name'</span></a>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**OR:** If you do not want to change the HTML

```js
$(".pdfarea > ul a > span").click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    console.log(txt);
});
function pdfDownload(){}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'pdfarea'>
  <ul class = 'pdflist'>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="javascript:pdfDownload('/pdf_name/spec_name.pdf'); return false;"><span class="icon-left"> 'banner name'</span></a>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

If the banner name outside the `span` try the following:

```js
$("div.pdf-area ul a").click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    console.log(txt);
});

function pdfDownload(){}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'pdf-area'>
  <ul class = 'pdf list'>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="javascript:pdfDownload('/pdf_name/spec_name.pdf'); return false;"><span class="icon-left"></span> 'banner name'</a>

    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't understand what you mean in case of can't change html, 'function pdfDownload(){}'. that function means above case function?

Comment: @송준석, that because you have mentioned ...`it's not my code and don't have any autohrity that can modify this code`

Comment: i mean  OR: If you do not want to change the HTML code you wirte empty function  that named pdfDownload. i don't know what means and works.

Comment: @송준석, when jQuery click is executed it also looks for the function `pdfDownload`. If you do not have function in that name in the code, it will give you an error. That's why I have declared a function in that name....thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. And, I would appreciate one more thing.

Comment: In the above code, my banner name is out of span. I don't know how to get a string that belongs only to <a> link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class = 'pdf-area'>
    <ul class = 'pdflist'>
        <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:pdfDownload('/pdf_name/spec_name.pdf'); return false;"><span class="icon-left"> 'banner name'</span></a>

        </li>
   </ul>
</div>

$(document).on('click','.pdflist a',function(){
      alert($(this).text());
})
```

Above click event will give the text on the current element

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gokulmaha/vt3b0keu/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `$("div.pdf-area ul a").click(function(i)..` and create `pdfDownload` function which will handle both

```js
function pdfDownload(e, path) {
  console.log(path)
  e.preventDefault();
  var txt = $(e.target).text();
  console.log(txt);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='pdf-area'>
  <ul class='pdf list'>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="pdfDownload(event ,'/pdf_name/spec_name.pdf')"><span class="icon-left"> 'banner name'</span></a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try this -

```
 $("div.pdf-area ul a").click(function(i) {
            var txt = $("div.pdf-area > ul.list > li a span.icon-left").text();
            console.log(txt);
        });
```